# How can I implement SharePoint JSGrid filtering and grouping functionality?

Tags: development, javascript, object-model, delegate-control

I am working on SharePoint JSGrid. I am able to implement the sort functionality in JSGrid. Now I want to implement the grouping and filtering in my custom JSGrid.

For filtering we have to attached the following delegate to the JSGrid control.

```
SP.JsGrid.DelegateType.GetAutoFilterEntries
```

When I applied this to my function I am getting loading... message every time. I guess this is due to the empty function delegate I used.

Please see the attached image with this.

[image]

I just need help: How can I show the filter menu in JSGrid?

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    Type.registerNamespace("GridManager");

    GridManager = function () {

        // Variables for the JSGrid control instance and the grid properties. 
        var _jsGridControl;
        var _props;
        // Variables for sorting. 
        var _orderByColumnName;
        var _isDescending;
        var _Command;
        // Variable for the grid data source. 
        var _tableCache;
        var _filter;
        this.Init = function (jsGridControl, initialData, props) {
            // Assign it to global variable 
            _jsGridControl = jsGridControl;
            _props = props;
            // Delegate to handle sort 


            // jsGridControl.tableViewParams.bAutoFilterableColumns = true;

            jsGridControl.SetDelegate(SP.JsGrid.DelegateType.Sort, HandleSort);

            jsGridControl.SetDelegate(SP.JsGrid.DelegateType.GetAutoFilterEntries, FilterMenu);

            jsGridControl.SetDelegate(SP.JsGrid.DelegateType.LaunchFilterDialog, FilterDialog);

            jsGridControl.SetDelegate(SP.JsGrid.DelegateType.AutoFilter, HandleFilter);

            var dataSource = new SP.JsGrid.StaticDataSource(initialData);
            // grid data source 
            _tableCache = dataSource.tableCache;
            var jsGridParams = dataSource.InitJsGridParams();

            jsGridParams.tableViewParams.bAutoFilterableColumns = true;

            jsGridControl.Init(jsGridParams);

        }

        function FilterDialog(newState) {

        }


        function FilterMenu() { 


        }


        function HandleFilter(newState) {

            _filter = newState;
            _jsGridControl.Disable();
            var args = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize({
                Command: "Filter",
                FilterField: _filter[0].columnName,
                FilterValue: _filter[0],
                FilterOp: "Eq"
            });

            eval(_props.callbackScript);
            // alert("Handle Filter," + "Title" + ":" + newState["Title"]);
        }



        // HandleSort is called when the ascending/descending header dropdown is clicked. 
        function HandleSort(newSortedCols) {

            _orderByColumnName = newSortedCols[0].columnName;
            _isDescending = newSortedCols[0].isDescending;
            _Command = "Sort";
            // Disable the grid while it is being sorted. 
            _jsGridControl.Disable();
            // Send the sorting values to the server by using a callback. 
            var args = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize({
                OrderByColumnName: _orderByColumnName,
                IsDescending: _isDescending
                , Command: _Command
            });

            eval(_props.callbackScript);
        }


        // The DisplaySortedData function is called through the GridManager instance (named "GM").

        // Bind the sorted data to the JSGrid object, and show the grid again.

        this.DisplaySortedData = function (sortedData) {
            // Show the sorted data in the grid. 
            if (sortedData && sortedData != '') {
                var deserializedGridData = SP.JsGrid.Deserializer.DeserializeFromJson(sortedData);
                var jsgridDeserializer = new SP.JsGrid.Deserializer(deserializedGridData, SP.JsGrid.DeserializationMode.RowView, _props.keyColumn);
                _tableCache.Clear();
                _tableCache.AddRawDataToCache(ConvertAssocArrayKeysToArray(jsgridDeserializer.data), jsgridDeserializer.data);
                _jsGridControl.SetRowView(jsgridDeserializer.InitJsGridRowViewParams());
                _jsGridControl.Enable();
            }

        }





        function ConvertAssocArrayKeysToArray(assocArray) {
            var r = [];
            for (var key in assocArray) {
                r.push(key);
            }
            return r;
        }

    };



</script>
```

I need help on how to write the FiterMenu function code.

Answer (score 1):

To show values and not "Loading", when you initialize GridSerializer, you need fill 2 more properties: EnableAutoFilterEntryGeneration and AutoFilterColumnKeys, and when you create "GridColumn",set IsAutoFilterable = true

Example:
GridColumn initialization:

```
*GridColumn col = new GridColumn();
col.FieldKey = "DepartmentManager";
col.Name = "DepartmentManager";
col.Width = 210;
col.IsAutoFilterable = true;*
```

Grid serializer intialization:

```
*GridSerializer gds = new GridSerializer(SerializeMode.Full,
                    data, "Key", new FieldOrderCollection(new String[] { "Department" }),
                    GridUtilities.GetGridFields(data), GridUtilities.GetGridColumns(data));
gds.EnableAutoFilterEntryGeneration = true;
gds.AutoFilterColumnKeys = new List<string>() { "Department Manager" };*
```

[image]

whether you need custom filters, col.IsAutoFilterable must be false;

Javascript code:

```
   *//Delegate GetAutoFilterEntries
   _jsGridControl.SetDelegate(SP.JsGrid.DelegateType.GetAutoFilterEntries, FilterMenu);*
```

//In function FilterMenu, fnSuccess need custom values:

```
*function FilterMenu(currentAutoFilterState, initiatingColumnKey, columnKeys, fnSuccess, fnFailure) {  
      var _autoFilterEntries = { "Title": [{ "displayString": "Task 1.1", "dataValue": "Task 1.1" }, { "displayString": "Task 1.2", "dataValue": "Task 1.2" }, { "displayString": "Task 1.3", "dataValue": "Task 1.3"}] };
      setTimeout(function () {
            fnSuccess(_autoFilterEntries);
      }, 500);
}*
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Did you had a look at this series of articles? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535898.aspx under the article related to Hierarchical data http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407273.aspx

Have you considered any alternatives such as jQuery with jSON and REST?

Comment: Thanks if you provide me some more link related to SP.JsGrid.DelegateType.GetAutoFilterEntries

Comment: Tried this on MSDN Blogs? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/01/18/enabling-sorting-in-a-js-grid-control.aspx

Comment: Yes I go through this blog. But unable to find how to enable filtering. If you have any idea to enabling filtering it will be a great help for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
     gds.EnableAutoFilterEntryGeneration = true;
```